# Distinguish various hyphens: U+00AD and U+2011

Tags: highlight-chars

According to the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text-Display.html), emacs

> displays U+00AD (soft hyphen), U+2010 (hyphen), and U+2011 (non-breaking hyphen) with the escape-glyph face.

Which is fine to distinguish them from the ASCII hyphen/dash/minus character, but I'd like to be able to distinguish these three funny hyphens from each other, too.

Answer (score 1):

If you use library [**`highlight-chars.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight-chars.el) you can highlight any characters any way you like.

Out of the box, you have command **`toggle-highlight-hard-hyphens`**, as well as functions `hc-highlight-hard-hyphens` and `hc-dont-highlight-hard-hyphens`, all of which control just hard-hyphen (U+2011) highlighting.

Other than that, you have general commands and functions to highlight groups of characters.  The most general of these are commands **`hc-highlight-chars`** and **`hc-toggle-highlight-other-chars`**.   For `hc-toggle-highlight-other-chars`, you can also specify characters that are to be *excluded* from
highlighting.

> **hc-highlight-chars** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>    [**`highlight-chars.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight-chars.el).
>
> `(hc-highlight-chars CHARS FACE &optional OFFP MSGP)`
>
> Read a string of characters and a face name, then highlight the chars.
>    With a prefix arg, unhighlight the chars.
>
> As an alternative to a string of characters, what you enter for the
>    characters can be any of the possibilities for a single entry in
>    `hc-other-chars`.  That is, it can be any of the following:
>
> - A cons (C1 . C2), where C1 and C2 are characters, that is, integers,
>     which you can represent using character notation.  This represents
>     the range of characters from C1 through C2.
>
>   For example, you would enter `(?a . ?g)` to mean the characters from
>     `a` through `g`, inclusive.  Note that you enter the parentheses and
>     the dot, and you can use character read syntax (e.g., `?a` for `a`).
> - A character class, such as `[:digit:]`.  This matches all characters
>     in the class.  You must type the brackets and colons (`:`).
> - A character set, such as `iso-8859-1` or `lao`.  This matches all
>     characters in the set.
>
> If you mistype one of the above representations, then what you type is
>    interpreted as just a string of the characters to highlight.  For
>    example, if you mean to type `[:digit:]` but you instead type
>    `[:digit]` (no second colon), then the characters highlighted are
>    [, :, d, g, i, t, and ].
>
> Non-interactively:
>
> - CHARS is a possible value for `hc-other-chars`, that is, a list of
>     entries such as described above.
> - FACE is the face to use (e.g., a symbol).
> - Non-nil OFFP non-nil means turn highlighting off.